# Other way to Remove an Item from the ListView by not removing it's content?

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to Remove an item from the ListView by not removing it's `content[]` ?

I tried changing the visibility of an item, but it does not give that *removed* effect it in. Instead it just gives you an empty space in between the data.

i.e.

```
    var customNodes : Foo[] = [Foo{bar:"help"}, 
                       Foo{bar:"me"}, Foo{bar:"please"}];   
    ListView { 
      ...
      contents : bind customNodes;
    }
```

Now, If i change `customNodes[1].visible = false;` the node does not display as expected.

But `Foo[1]` Still eats space between `customNodes[0]` and `customNodes[2]` resulting in gaps between the nodes.

This can be done by doing the following statement instead:

```
    delete customNodes[1];
```

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to *actually* delete data from the list. Thus, need to rely on visibility

So again, Is it possible to Remove an item from the ListView by not removing it's `content[]` ?

if not, any suggestions on how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But if you want it to behave like that without actually removing the list. You can add a property to your CustomNode. Then check for that property when adding data to the list.

i.e.

```
    var customNodes : Foo[] = [Foo{bar:"help" isDismissed : false}, 
                  Foo{bar:"me" isDismissed : true}, 
                  Foo{bar:"please" isDismissed : false}];
```

Then in your ItemList do:

```
    ItemList{ 
       content : bind [
                for (node in CustomNodes) 
                   if(node.isDismissed) [] else [node]
       ]
    }
```

This way you are not actually deleting data from customNodes but just decides which should be rendered in the ItemList.